# why is the blue color not adding up?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i am making a project with bootstrap 4  and the blue color which i want to add to its body is not adding up . i have include the site with the bootstrap cdn and the one of my style sheet 
 html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- our css  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Aurora Grove</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- navbar come from here  -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark ">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aurora Grove</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">explore</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">contact</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">book</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

css file

```
body
{
    background-color: blue ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably defined the wrong path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
```

Try this:

```
href="../app.css"
```

You should also include file architecture in the question so we could see where your CSS file is...

Comment: Please share folder structure because without it we can just guess...

Answer (score -1):

```css
html > body
{
    background-color: blue ;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- our css  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Aurora Grove</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- navbar come from here  -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark ">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aurora Grove</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">explore</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">contact</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">book</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```